# Is it possible to check if a phone number is real or not in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have thousands of random phone numbers and I wanted to check which one of them are real and working right now. is_valid_number and is_possible_number methods in phonenumbers library won't solve my issue.
Is there any way to identify through Python? Any way maybe through which we send a ping as an sms to the list of numbers and could get some kind of response back to validate the phone numbers.
I have seen few posts on stackoverflow like this [International phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406765/international-phone-number-validation)
but they are simply validating either the format of the phone numbers or the possibility if the numbers can be right or not. But my requirement is that I want to know if the phone numbers are working in real life or not.

I have tried using phonenumbers library but there is no such method. I couldn't find anything relevant on the web too.

Comment: Did you look at Twilio ? They can track status of SMS (delivered or not) via their API in Python. https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python

Comment: No, but seems like it may work. Thank you @DamDam.

Comment: SMS will not work on landlines. You'd really have to call to check.

Comment: How did you acquire these numbers and why do you want to know if those are working?

Comment: It will be great for everyone if you'll add the context you provided to the question as well @JatinDeswal